# Communication with a service after kerberos authentication

Tags: kerberos

I read several articles about Kerberos Authentication protocol and one thing elludes from me. How does a client principal interracts with a service after successful authentication? The articles I read usually usually do not explain what happens afterwards. E.g. the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerberos_(protocol)#Client_Service_Request) on Kerberos states that after the successful authentication "The server provides the requested services to the client". How does it look in practice? Assuming a client interacts with a requested service over http, should it send some kinde of a token in the requests' headers?

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming a client interacts with a requested service over http, should it send some kinde of a token in the requests' headers?

That's not "after" successful authentication – the token *is* the authentication. For HTTP, headers are the only way to transmit the Kerberos ticket and authenticator in the first place (it does not have any kind of pre-request handshake that could be used for this purpose), so every HTTP request includes a fresh authenticator (together with the ticket) within the `Authorization` header.

Usually the `Negotiate` HTTP auth mechanism ([RFC 4559](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4559)) is used for this purpose (sending the authentication data inside GSSAPI and SPNEGO) – it looks a whole lot like "Basic" or "Bearer" authentication. You can use `python-pyspnego` or `python-gssapi` to experiment with creating tokens.

Most other protocols also use the standard GSSAPI token format (sometimes inside SASL, sometimes not), although in most other cases, the authentication is only done once per connection.

What happens *after* authentication isn't really mandated by Kerberos – it's no different from verifying a password, the protocol can proceed in whichever way it wants. The protocol *may* use Kerberos for encryption or integrity (i.e. "wrapping"), again usually via GSSAPI, but most protocols don't do that, relying instead on TLS. (LDAP, MS-RPC, and NFS/SunRPC are the exceptions.)